# Crystal Reports exporting to Excel Issue

Tags: excel, crystal-reports

In a current C# application I do maintenance on, we have upgraded to Visual Studio 2008 from Visual Studio 2003. We have always used the included Crystal Reports that came with Visual Studio.

Since the upgrade we have found an issue with our reports when exporting to excel. If the column in the details section is null, then all the rest of the data in the row shifts to the left. Casuing data to be put in the incorrect columns.

I have been searching, and checking properties and have come up empty handed. If anyone can throw me a lifeline or point me in the right direction I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that with CR, if you know that the data will mostly be dumped to excel, I remove ALL formatting that CR may do.  Is this the case with your report?

What is CR set to do in it's properties with NULL values?

Comment: This is the case. I actually made a seperate CR report for just excel. This worked in VS 2003 to get the aligning correct. But in 2008 it is not working anymore. When you say you remove all formatting, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Do you know what the property name is for dealing with Null values. I found a couple dealing with Suppress, and they are all set to false. I remembered the 2003 version had something that explicitly said NULL but I can not seem to find this one.

Comment: I don't let CR apply any formatting and put the fields on the workspace in the order I want them in my Excel spreadsheet.  That being said, I misread your post.  It sounds like you're using the CR version in VS, which I'm not as familiar with.  In CRXI Developer Edition or CR2008, you can let CR..

Comment: ...handle the null values, which usually helps with your column issue.

Comment: Ahh..Yeah I think I may be hitting a limit of the Basic version. I do appreciate your help though and thanks for your time and effort.